# Splitting DokuWiki topics between teams

Tags: dokuwiki

I'm looking at possibly setting up DokuWiki for some group documentation, but it's complicated by the fact that there will be multiple overlapping teams. Individuals may be members of one or more teams, and so would be using the wiki for information relating to each team they're assigned to.

I like DokuWiki because of its simplicity (file based, simple web server is all that's needed), but how would you split articles into different team sections like this? Is there a way to flag the articles so that they pertain to different teams, or should I set up a separate wiki for each team?

Answer (score 1):

After digging a little more (re: reading the docs), I came across Groups, Sections, and ACLs.

By splitting my pages into Sections, I can keep them organized based on topics. Then, I create groups for access to each section. Finally, I use the ACLs to control which groups may view each section.

The result is that pages which aren't available to someone (based on their group membership) don't even show up. The ones that do are labeled with the section name, clearly delineating subject matter for those with multiple group memberships.